# How to confirm newsletter subscriber mail id in magento admin panel

Tags: email, newsletter

I have gotten a few new subscribers via my website. But the subscriber status not activated in Magento panel. How do I change the status?

[image]

Comment: which version of magento you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the checkbox from the grid, and select option from the **status** drop-down.

As far as I know, STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE is used for Newsletter confirmation:

Enable Newsletter confirmation:

> STORE > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Newsletter > Need to confirm > No.

Answer (score 3):

[image]Check the checkbox from list of subscribers and change the status from action drop-down. Click submit button. All done. Check image for details.